How can I optimize the reactivity in my R Shiny App?
I am putting together a shiny app that is six pages of differing inputs and ways of plotting the same data. The first page works ok, but has less reactivity. After putting together the second page, it is very slow to load the graph. It takes several minutes, which is of course too long for any level of functionality. Am I doing something fundamentally wrong with the structure of the reactivity, my server side and UI side?
Note: Of course, I created a minimal reproducible example for the purpose of asking this question, and that one works plenty fast enough. The only difference between the two is the reading in of the data vs manually creating some fake data, as well as some theme options. I don't think the data is large enough to slow it down this badly. The file I read in is 8.2mb RDS file with 620579 obs of 21 variables.
From some debugging and using reactlog and prof vis, it seems I have created some sort of reactive loop and the app bounces the inputs back and forth thousands of times before sending it to the plot. I wanted to address the problem now before continuing with putting together the other 4 pages of the app.
Initially, I thought my problem was the size of the data. I was reading in a csv originally and compared all the read-in methods I could find and readRDS was way faster than the original method. But there was no improvement on the app speed.
Anyway, below is the minimal reproducible example of my app.
Here's my global declarations and a simulation of my data:
#Reading in Libraries
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(plotly)
library(bslib)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(shinycssloaders)
options = shinyWidgets::pickerOptions(style = "btn-outline-primary")

options.vector <- c("Option 1", "Option 2", "Option 3")
opt1.vec <- c("Level01", "Level02", "Level03", "Level04", "Level05", "Level06", 
              "Level07", "Level08", "Level09", "Level10", "Level11", "Level12")
opt2.vec <- c("Level01", "Level02", "Level03", "Level04", "Level05", "Level06", 
              "Level07", "Level08", "Level09", "Level10", "Level11", "Level12", 
              "Level13", "Level14", "Level15")
opt3.vec <- c("Level01", "Level02", "Level03", "Level04", "Level05", "Level06", 
              "Level07", "Level08", "Level09", "Level10", "Level11", "Level12", 
              "Level13", "Level14", "Level15", "Level16")
g1.vec <- c("L01", "L02", "L03", "L04", "L05", "L06", "L07", "L08", "L09", "L10", "L11", "L12", "L13", "L14", "L15", "L16")
group2.vec <- c("Level01", "Level02", "Level03", "Level04", "Level05", "Level06", "Level07", "Level08", "Level09", "Level10", "Level11")

groupOpt <- c(rep("Option 1", times =200000), rep("Option 2", times =200000), rep("Option 3", times =200000))

group1 <- c(sample(x=opt1.vec, size=200000, replace= TRUE),
  sample(x=opt2.vec, size=200000, replace= TRUE),
  sample(x=opt3.vec, size=200000, replace= TRUE))

group2 <- sample(x=group2.vec, size=600000, replace= TRUE)

data0 <- data.frame(groupOpt, group1, group2)

data <- data0 %>% mutate(g1= case_when(
  group1 == "Level01"~ "L01",
  group1 == "Level02"~ "L02",
  group1 == "Level03" ~ "L03",
  group1 == "Level04" ~ "L04",
  group1 == "Level05" ~ "L05",
  group1 == "Level06" ~ "L06",
  group1 == "Level07" ~ "L07",
  group1 == "Level08" ~ "L08",
  group1 == "Level09" ~ "L09",
  group1 == "Level10" ~ "L10",
  group1 == "Level11" ~ "L11",
  group1 == "Level12" ~ "L12",
  group1 == "Level13" ~ "L13",
  group1 == "Level14" ~ "L14",
  group1 == "Level15" ~ "L15",
  group1 == "Level16" ~ "L16"
)) 

Here's my UI code
theme0 <- bs_theme(bootswatch="spacelab")

ui <- page_navbar(
  title = "Dashboard Name",
  id = "navbar",
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Theme-----
  theme = theme0, 
  header = tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
  .pickerClass {font-size: 75%; line-height: 1.6;}
                  ")
    )
  ),
  #--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------Tab 2-----
  nav_panel(
    id="page2",
    title = "Page 2",
    navset_card_pill(
      id="page2_navset",
      title = "Page 2 Title",
      sidebar = sidebar(
        radioGroupButtons(
          inputId = "page2_input1",
          label = "Option:",
          selected = "Option 3",
          choices = options.vector,
          status = "info",
          size = "sm"
        ),
        conditionalPanel(
          "input.page2_navset === 'Page 2 Tab 2 Title'",
          pickerInput(
            inputId = "page2_input2",
            label = "Select options:",
            choices = NULL,
            selected = NULL,
            multiple = TRUE,
            options = list(
              `actions-box` = TRUE,
              `selected-text-format` = "count",
              `count-selected-text` = "{0} options chosen",
              `none-selected-text` = "Select at least one option",
              style = "pickerClass"
            ),
            choicesOpt = list(
              style = rep_len("font-size: 75%; line-height: 1.6;", 16)
            )
          )
        ),
        actionButton("page2.button",
                     "Update Plot",
                     width = "80%",
                     class="btn-warning",
                     style="position:absolute; bottom: 15px;",
                     icon=icon("refresh")
        )
      ),
      
      nav_panel(
        id="page2_tab1",
        title="Page 2 Tab 1 Title",
        card_body(
          h3(textOutput('page2.tab1.title'), align = "center"),
          uiOutput('page2.tab1.ui')
        )
      ),
      nav_panel(
        id="page2_tab2",
        title="Page 2 Tab 2 Title",
        card_body(
          h3(textOutput('page2.tab2.title'), align = "center"),
          uiOutput('page2.tab2.ui')
        )
      )
    )
  )
  #------------------------------------------End of page_navbar------------------------------------------- 
)


and lastly here's my server code
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  options(warn = -1) 
  #page 2
  observeEvent(input$page2, {
    print(paste0("value of page2: ", input$page2))
  })
  observeEvent(input$page2_navset, {
    print(paste0("value of page2_navset: ", input$page2_navset))
  })
  observeEvent(input$page2_input1, {
    print(paste0("value of page2_input1: ", input$page2_input1))
  })
  observeEvent(input$page2_input2, {
    print(paste0("value of page2_input2: ", input$page2_input2))
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$page2_input1, {
    page2PickerOptions <- data %>% 
      ungroup() %>% 
      filter(groupOpt==input$page2_input1) %>% 
      distinct(group1) %>% 
      pull()
    
    updatePickerInput(
      session = session,
      inputId = "page2_input2",
      label = "Select options:",
      choices = page2PickerOptions,
      selected = page2PickerOptions,
      options = list(
        actionsBox = TRUE,
        selectedTextFormat = "count",
        countSelectedText = "{0} options chosen",
        noneSelectedText = "Select at least one option",
        style = "pickerClass"
      ),
      choicesOpt = list(
        style = rep_len("font-size: 75%; line-height: 1.6;", 16)
      )
    )
  })
  
  observeEvent(input$page2.button, {
    
    output$page2.tab1.ui <- renderUI({
      withSpinner(plotlyOutput("page2.tab1"), type=4)
    })
    
    output$page2.tab2.ui <- renderUI({
      withSpinner(plotlyOutput("page2.tab2"), type=4)
    })
    
    page2.plot.title <- reactive(if(input$page2_input1 == "Option 1"){
      "Option 1 Plot Title"
    } else if(input$page2_input1 == "Option 2"){
      "Option 2 Plot Title"
    } else if(input$page2_input1 == "Option 3"){
      "Option 3 Plot Title"
    })
    
    output$page2.tab1 <- renderPlotly({
      data %>%
        filter(groupOpt == isolate(input$page2_input1)) %>% 
        group_by(group2) %>% 
        distinct(group2) %>% 
        summarise(count=n()) %>% 
        plot_ly(labels=~group2, values=~count, sort=FALSE) %>% 
        add_pie(hole=0.5) %>% 
        layout(title = isolate(page2.plot.title()), showlegend= T,
               xaxis = list(showgrid=FALSE, zeroline=FALSE, showticklabels=FALSE),
               yaxis = list(showgrid=FALSE, zeroline=FALSE, showticklabels=FALSE)) %>% 
        config(displaylogo = FALSE)
    })
    
    output$page2.tab2 <- renderPlotly({
      data %>%
        filter(groupOpt == isolate(input$page2_input1)) %>% 
        filter(group1 %in% isolate(input$page2_input2)) %>% 
        group_by(group2, g1, group1) %>% 
        summarise(ppl.in.group2=n()) %>% 
        plot_ly(x=~ppl.in.group2, y=~g1, color=~group2, type='bar', name=~group2) %>% 
        layout(title = isolate(page2.plot.title()), 
               yaxis = list(title = 'Group 2', categoryorder='trace', autorange='reversed'),
               xaxis = list(title = 'Percent of people'),
               
               barmode = 'stack', barnorm='percent') %>% 
        config(displaylogo = FALSE)
      
    })
    
    output$page2.tab1.title<- renderText({
      "Page 2 Tab 1 Title"
    })
    output$page2.tab2.title <- renderText({
      "Page 2 Tab 2 Title"
    })
    
  })

  
  session$onSessionEnded(function() {
    stopApp()
  })  
  #-----------------------------------------End Server-----------------------------------------------------  
}
if (interactive())
  # Run the application 
  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)

Please HELP!

Why do you have a number of input objects wrapped in isolate()?

And you shouldn’t wrap reactives and observers inside each other. That’s a recipe for disaster.

@IfeanyiIdiaye I may be mistaken but I thought that was necessary to prevent the inputs from updating server side whenever they are changed in the UI, I only wanted them to update when the action button was pressed. Sounds like this is not the case? Please advise if so.

@limey ok! for the title, if I remove the reactive, it should still only update when the button is clicked, because its inside the observeEvent, right? I knew I was overkilling it somehow.

You may want to consider the fst package for data retrieval - its' MUCH faster than RDS.  You are correct that isolate() is to prevent changes from triggering reactivity.

@EddieRowe I had heard this before, and when I benchmarked and compared the two, readRDS was faster in my case. I am not sure why. Maybe I'll give fst another go now that the app is further along.

For anyone else stumbling on this: I ended up sorting out the issue after the commenters here highlighted the source of the issue.  I unwrapped the whole plot portion from the observeEvent. Then I used eventReactive to create reactive objects based on the inputs from the UI, reacting only when the button was clicked. I used these in place of the isolate(input$blank) in the filter steps. I used the same logic for the title as well. I'm not sure how to answer myself in a longer format here or I'd post the updated code.
